# How to plot geom_errorbar with custom values (meta-analysis in R or maybe forest?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Can anyone help me a bit with plotting a geom_errorbar in R, when my data looks:

```
> Country Sex Correlation Number  Lower Upper
1  Brazil  Men      -0.108    301 -0.218 0.005
2 Bulgaria Men      -0.012     63 -0.258 0.236
3   Canada Men        0.07     25 -0.334 0.452
4   Brazil Women    -0.074     47 -0.353 0.217
5 Bulgaria Women    -0.042    300 -0.154 0.071
6  Canada  Women     0.092     51 -0.188 0.358
```

I want to visualize differences in correlations in countries, with respect to sex (filled/coloured sex). I have a mean (Correlation), lower confidence interval for that mean (Lower), and upper (Upper). On the left there should be countries and... basically that's it. Somehow I can't get to it.

When searching through Stackoverflow I wondered if maybe I should rather use some forest functions, as it is perhaps closer to what I imagined.

What I managed to do so far is looking rather poor:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tyi2.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you want your graph to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Correlation, y = Country, color = Sex)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = Lower, xmax = Upper),
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))
```

[image]

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(Country = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
    .Label = c("Brazil", "Bulgaria", "Canada"), class = "factor"), 
    Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Men", "Women"), 
    class = "factor"), 
    Correlation = c(-0.108, -0.012, 0.07, -0.074, -0.042, 0.092
    ), Number = c(301L, 63L, 25L, 47L, 300L, 51L), Lower = c(-0.218, 
    -0.258, -0.334, -0.353, -0.154, -0.188), Upper = c(0.005, 
    0.236, 0.452, 0.217, 0.071, 0.358)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly something like that!!! It looks awesome! However, there is a problem with this 'dot' that should be in the middle... It appears somewhere where it should not appear... Definitely not in the middle: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kBGB9DHYEelbYEJY7zIDuIGu6A2e6FfH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Uups, my fault... I just noticed with str(df) that these were coded as char not int... Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach using facets from `ggplot2` package with `facet_wrap()`. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Country,y=Correlation,color=Sex))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Lower,ymax=Upper))+
  facet_wrap(.~Sex)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Country = c("Brazil", "Bulgaria", "Canada", "Brazil", 
"Bulgaria", "Canada"), Sex = c("Men", "Men", "Men", "Women", 
"Women", "Women"), Correlation = c(-0.108, -0.012, 0.07, -0.074, 
-0.042, 0.092), Number = c(301L, 63L, 25L, 47L, 300L, 51L), Lower = c(-0.218, 
-0.258, -0.334, -0.353, -0.154, -0.188), Upper = c(0.005, 0.236, 
0.452, 0.217, 0.071, 0.358)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: That is some neat plotting. With the extra lines on theme you Sir made it look awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @chillos Yeah it looks nice. I hope it helped you :) And as the other answer is cool too, you could upvote :)